# Assisted staff or assisted the staff

Tags: definite-articles

I'm currently updating my CV. I'm not sure whether to say "assisted the staff" or "assisted staff". Could anyone explain me the difference between the first and the second expression, please? Thanks

Comment: Both are acceptable; using the definite article here gives a rather less impersonal effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> Both are acceptable; using the definite article here gives a rather less impersonal effect.